# Proof of Riemann-Roch using Mittag-Leffler

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

In the introduction for Rick Miranda's book "algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces", it says that they will prove Riemann-Roch "in an algebraic manner, via an adaptation of the adelic proof, expressed completely in terms of solving a Mittag-Leffler problem".

I was wondering about the original adelic proof, and how it is related to the Mittag-Leffler problem. Is there a connection between adeles and the Mittag-Leffler problem?

Comment: He probably means proving it for curves over finite fields by using Poisson summation for functions on the adeles. This is done, for example, in Tate's thesis. I think for the second part your parsing the sentence wrong, I believe. It should be "in an algebraic manner (via an adaptation of the adelic proof) expressed completely in terms of solving a Mittag-Leffler problem". I have no idea how the adelic proof has to do with a Mittag-Leffler problem except via Riemann-Roch (which is, definitionally, a Mittag-Leffler problem).